# RS232 module an USB to serial cable it the PL-2303

Tags: gpio, pi-3, serial

I am preparing to use a Raspberry Pi 3 for the first time and I have some questions:

1. Can I use 2 USB to serial cables to connect it to a PL-2303?
2. Does the Raspberry Pi 3 have support for two RS232 modules from the GPIO header?

Comment: I suspect English is not your first language, but the question makes no sense. Also, if you expect any answers you need to provide more detail about what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: How many RS232 module can connect to the Pi ?

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I fail to see how either of the people who edited this question (which is at least now English) can KNOW what the OP actually intended?

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand what you try to achieve, but I will try to answer in a way that is meaningful. There are two ways that I can understand the question, and both of them means you are probably overcomplicating things.

The PL-2303 is a USB-to-Serial adapter.

If you want to use the pi's USB connection to drive UART, then you can do it cheaper and simpler by using the GPIO for UART directly. You wouldn't need the PL-2303.

If you want to use the pi's GPIO for UART, and use the PL-2303 to convert it to USB, then you are better of using the pi's USB connection in the first place.

I have a hard time seeing the use of a PL-2303 in connection to a raspberry pi.